# Html.BeginAjaxForm returning data from action and injecting it into the user's DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

let's suppose I have a form like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", new { area = "UserSettings" }, new
 AjaxOptions
 {
  HttpMethod = "POST",
  OnSuccess = "ShowMessage('Password successfully changed')"

 }, null))
 {
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PasswordConfirm, new { placeholder = "Confirm password", @class = "form-control", @type = "password" })<br />
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordConfirm, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @style = "float:right;" })
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
 }
```

Essentially it's a form to change a password with validation setup in place.

Now my Question here is, in the case where I have an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ChangePassword")]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(MyObjectClass model)
{
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
return View(model);
}
else{
ViewBag.MyData = // some data here;
return View();
}
}
```

The questions that I have are:

- When I return a View with all data in it, how do I actually then inject that returned data into the user's DOM that the user can see the changes reflected when OnSuccess method is called? Where is the "data" object that I can inject into like in done function in jQuery( .done(function(data)))?
- What is the easiest way here to transfer now all the data from my controller action into the OnSuccess method and actually let the user see the outcome of the method that they called?

Can someone help me out with this ? What is the best way to solve this issue ?

I used to work with pure jQuery before and I Was doing this in this manner:

```
$.post("/linktomymethod",{/*some parameters*/).done(function(data){
// then inject the returned data into the browser's DOM
}));
```

Comment: Why would you use `Ajax` methods instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke not sure what do you mean ? Could you clarify it to me abit more ? :)

Comment: i tried to use Ajax form but here its kinda restricted interns of flexibility i would advice u to use jquery ajax instead of ajax begin form for the reason a>its easy to understand and is more flexible and b> i really dont think here is much good in ajax.begin form

Comment: The MVC team are not even supporting the `Ajax` methods any more. Using the jQuery methods give you much more flexibility. But since you returning a view (which should be a partial view, you just specify the `UpdateTargetID` option.

Comment: You can use partial view with jquery load method to fill partial view into target dom element. And you can use UpdateTargetId as @StephenMuecke said

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes exactly, which is why I loved the jquery methods instead of this.. But I thought using built in features like these is the way to go (and that microsoft would recommend it).. But looks like I was wrong in this case... By the way... the reason why I used ajax methods is because of displaying the validation errors... I'm not really sure how to display 10 error messages for 10 different properties which may need to be validated in the form , which is why I opted to use this way .. ?

Comment: @User987 why dont you use partial view with your model then you can parse your model errors into partial view and you can show it in main view.

Comment: You have not given enough information to understand what your wanting to do with validation messages

Comment: @StephenMuecke Let's suppose I have 10 textboxes in my HTML and I pass them into the method in my controller as an object (via the automatic javascript object binding). And in my view model i have these 10 properties all marked as required [Required]... so if 5/10 of these aren't validated and if the modelstate isn't valid, and when I return the view to display the error messages for the non validated inputs, how would I actually display error messages for each one of them ?

Comment: @user8175473 I have more than 1 update target... Theres multiple tables that needs to be updated when the data is returned from controller to view ... Would I then just supply multiple updatetargetid's ?

Comment: First, you should be testing `$('form').valid()` and if not, cancel the submit so client side validation messages are displayed). If you returning a partial view and that partial is based on an invalid model and contains `ValidationMessageFor()`, then those errors will be displayed when you add the partial to the DOM.

Comment: @User987 you can put yout tables into partial view and can fill it with controller then call this controller action with jquery load method in main view to parse your tables into target dom element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand it better now thanks... Could you show me this example that you were mentioning, let's say for this particular case of mine so that I can see exactly what do you mean ? :) 

Or even some links where I can read more about it ? \

Comment: @user8175473 aha okay thanks a lot i will have this ind my mind as well :)

Comment: @User987 your welcome:) you can take a look at jquery load examples and you can use it with client side validation so you will be able prevent this action if your form is not valid.

Comment: Its not clear why your using ajax here. Is that form a partial view that you render in your layout. And why are you returning the view if its all valid?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using Ajax or jQuery to prevent the page from refreshing each time the user clicks on the button inside the form. I thought that returning the view with the model is that way to go to display the error messages for each input that wasn't properly validated when the form was submited?

Comment: So is that form just part of a larger view? It would make no sense to use ajax if your view is just for changing the password.

Comment: @StephenMuecke what i'd like to do is to use jquery to submit the data from my HTML page, and then validate it with data annotations, and if model state isn't valid , i'd like to display which field isn;t validated properly and show it's error message, all without page needing to refresh. And if everything's okay then process the submitted data and display it onto the user's DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it's a part of a larger view... Actually it's a completely different view but I've put this one as an example ( not a good one now I see)... But essentially I'm trying to do this what I just wrote in comment above this one :)

Comment: But your existing `$.post()` code will inject the partial view your method returns into the DOM, and if its based on a model and `ModelState` is invalid, and the partial contains `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` then the errors will be displayed. I'm still not sure what your issue is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke omg you just answered my question hahaha... do I inject the partial view via .fail method or ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147729/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `@Ajax.BeginForm()`, then you specify the [UpdateTargetId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.updatetargetid(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions.UpdateTargetId) property of `AjaxOptions`, for example

```
<div id="changepassword">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(..., new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "changepassword" }, null))
    {
        ....
    }
<div>
```

which would replace your `<form>` element with the view returned by your `ChangePassword()` method. Note also that your should be returning a `PartialView`.

However, you should stick with the `$.ajax()` methods as these give you far more flexibility. Typically you handle the forms `.submit()` event, check the `.valid()` method (and cancel the ajax call if not so client side validation messages are displayed), and then update the DOM with the partial view that the method returns.

Replace your `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(..) {` code with a simple

```
<div id="changepassword">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        ....
```

and add the following script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ChangePassword", "User", new { area = "UserSettings" })';
$('form').submit(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
    if (!$(this).valid()) { // check if the data is valid
        return; // exit the function
    }
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();`
    $.post(url, formdata, function(response) {
        $('changepassword').html(response);
    });
});
```

To improve performance further, your could just return a `JsonResult` containing the invalid properties and their associated error, and update the placeholder elements generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. You controller code would be

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(k => ModelState[k].Errors.Count > 0).Select(k => new { propertyName = k, errorMessage = ModelState[k].Errors[0].ErrorMessage });
    return Json(errors);
}
// Save data
return Json(null);
```

In the success callback, you can then loop through the collection, find the corresponding `ValidationMessageFor()` placeholder based on the property name, and add the error message and appropriate class names.

Comment: As always, the best possible answer! Thanks a lot. Your replies bring light to this community ! :-)